# Determine what process or program is making a certain noise

Tags: 16.04, sound, noise

Every so often, at irregular intervals, my computer makes a strange beep. I think its a notification sound for something but I can't tell what its notifying me of, or what is even notifying me. Is there a way to determine which program is making this noise so I can put a stop to this?

Answer (score 4):

Most Ubuntu installations are using PulseAudio, then it is possible to

**List all processes which are connected to your pulse audio**

run this command `pactl list clients`

---

However, it will give you POSSIBLE sound-making processes, if you really want to:

***catch* the process making sound** then run this command:

`watch -n0.5 'pacmd list-sink-inputs | tee -a sound-inputs.log'`

and after a while you will see what processes are making sound, they could disappear fast, this is why `tee -a sound-inputs.log` command is storing/logging in `sound-inputs.log` all information, and you can review which process **exactly** is *making noise* now.

you can review it by `less sound-inputs` command, an example output is below:

```
0 sink input(s) available.
0 sink input(s) available.
0 sink input(s) available.
1 sink input(s) available.
    index: 277
    driver: <protocol-native.c>
    flags: START_CORKED 
    state: RUNNING
    sink: 0 <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
    volume: front-left: 55420 /  85% / -4.37 dB,   front-right: 55420 /  85% / -4.37 dB
            balance 0.00
    muted: no
    current latency: 35.85 ms
    requested latency: 7.52 ms
    sample spec: float32le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    resample method: copy
    module: 10
    client: 1884 <Chromium>
    properties:
        application.icon_name = "chromium-browser"
        media.name = "Playback"
        application.name = "Chromium"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "33"
        application.process.id = "2993986"
        application.process.user = "aneutrino"
        application.process.host = "xiexie"
        application.process.binary = "Discord"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        application.process.machine_id = "13335995d81e4f4faf75ac28835b4f8c"
        module-stream-restore.id = "sink-input-by-application-name:Chromium"
```

in the example, above it was `Discord` chat application using `chrome-browser` making noises `PID 2993986` I have entered to settings and disabled sounds in it, but alternatively I could simply kill it `kill 2993986`

Answer (score 1):

I found out just after I posted this. If you go to the "sound settings" menu and click on "applications" you can see which programs are using audio. I just had to wait for the beep to happen again to catch it.[image]