Chime or ding sound of unknown origin on Ubuntu 22.0.4.1
Background
I recently updated to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS and subsequently started noticing a chime or ding that my computer would produce seemingly at random. The sound is either this or something very close to it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bSWZMNz_ZiEBO2309vP736AD_9V0qbpm/view?usp=sharing. The file from the link is called "complete.oga" and was found in /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo on my machine. I can't find any sort of notification or window that the sound might be linked to, nor have I been able to identify what it is that I may be doing to trigger it. I tried deleting the sound file at the location I mentioned above but that didn't seem to change anything. There are a couple of other locations where an identically-named and -sounding file is located, but at least some of them are in read-only file systems and so I'm not sure how to delete them or if I should.
In case it's relevant here are my system details:
Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              HP HP Laptop 15-da0xxx
Memory:                                      12.0 GiB
Processor:                                   Intel® Core™ i7-8550U × 8
Graphics:                                    Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)
Disk Capacity:                               (null)

Software Information:

Firmware Version:                            F.36
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               46
Windowing System:                            Wayland
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.8.0-45-generic

Questions

Where is the chime sound coming from?
How can I make the chime sound stop?

Any and all advice is much appreciated.
Addendum
The question at Random bell sound notification in Ubuntu 22.04 is very similar to this one and it may be the same issue. This question is distinct because it asks for how to identify the source of the sound as well as for how to stop it, whereas the question at the link is "what's going on?". Also, the answers to the linked question (at least at the time of writing) do not address how to identify the source of the sound or how to make the sound stop beyond turning down the volume (if possible I would like to find a way to stop the sound from being produced in the first place).

This question is similar to: Random bell sound notification in Ubuntu 22.04. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

To track down an app running a sound try the strategy suggested in the answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/904057/determine-what-process-or-program-is-making-a-certain-noise
